# SQL Query from row of Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 10 years worth of data rows, which are in the format of "BW-YYYYMMDD-0001" (0001 resetting daily and being sequential, maximum 1000 each day)

For example the database will be called "Order_Det"

| Order | Order_Details | Information |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LUH | BW-20200501-0002 | Order Complete |

I used to only have 3 years worth of data but now all 10 years worth of data appears to now be pulling through.

I am struggling to think of how to do a SQL Query where I can grab the amount of rows in the database table for the last 36 months, do you have any idea how I could do this without having to drop the BW- nor the last 4 sequential numbers?

Comment: That format doesn't look like a **row** format, is it? Or do you mean that there is one column in your table, where the values look like what you showed? Then - is the format **exactly** as you show, in every row (in that column)? Finally, what is `qliksense` in your tags (below the question), and what does have to do with your question?

Comment: Sorry @mathguy I was editing the table, so I've got the database headers as 

Order / Order_Details / Information

All rows will be 

LUH / BW-YYYYMMDD-0001 / Order Complete etc.

Comment: I am not sure how to explain but I am trying to get a script to ignore BW then read the date and ignore the last 4 unique numbers so then I can create a script to show just the last 36 months

Comment: Fix the schema, so OrderDetails is three separate columns as it should be, and suddenly this is trivial.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the system it's being pulled from is 13 years old, it's in progress of being updated, but it's still a year or so out until it's ready... the next issue is that we then still need to replicate the previous years data unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a column `id` with values like you show, and you have an index on it, so you would like to take advantage of that. (Whether the optimizer will choose to use the index is another question - it may not, since you are retrieving about 30% of the data anyway.)

You could do something like this:

```
select .....
.....
where id >= 'BY-' || to_char(add_months(sysdate, -36), 'YYYYMMDD')
.....
```

The string on the right-hand side of the `where` condition would look something like `BY-20180105` (if the query is run on 5 January 2021). `add_months` adds -36 months (that is, -3 years) to "today".

EDIT: Of course, I am referring to `order_details` (which you just added) instead of `id`.